# Try to open new tables, but recieving error

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am new here, I am trying to make a connection to my database and open a new tables called "Sintabar". My code works but the data is not coming into my table.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection

Public Sub connect()
    Dim DatabaseName As String = "sql6141508"
    Dim server As String = "sql6.freemysqlhosting.net"
    Dim userName As String = "'******'"
    Dim password As String = "*******"
    If Not conn Is Nothing Then conn.Close()
    conn.ConnectionString = String.Format("server={0}; user id={1}; password={2}; database={3}; pooling=false", server, userName, password, DatabaseName)
    Try
        conn.Open()

        MsgBox("התחברת בהצלחה")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    conn.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    connect()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        conn.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(String.Format("CREATE TABLE sintabar (id INTEGER, name TEXT, age INTEGER);"))
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()

End Sub
End Class
```

Error msg:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in MySql.Data.dll. system.invalidOpertionException:
>   {"Connection must be valid and open."}

and yes, my user is the admin.

Comment: what error message do you get? Do the user you connect with has CREATE TABLE privileges?

Comment: hi nir. thenk your for fast respons. im get : An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll.
system.invalidOpertionException: {"Connection must be valid and open."}

and yes. my user is the admin..

Comment: well your create thingie is outside the try catch that (the try catch) just doesn't perform any useful info for you. So your try catch is done, then you just rifle off the query. Your `Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand` is not associated with any open connection. So it should be like `cmd.connection=conn` or thereabouts

Comment: Plutonix is around and I am sure he will sweep thru. Otherwise I could show you in c# which is virtually identical

Comment: You also need it all wrapped in a try catch (and a `using` block if you don't want to manually dispose). See the manual on that. c# visual of conn and using: http://i.imgur.com/ODQGFGp.jpg

Comment: thenk you for your halp. im try to see the manual you send me

Comment: `If Not conn Is Nothing Then conn.Close()` may be the problem, `conn` is never `Nothing`; you are trying to close a connection that was never opened (should probably check the connection status before trying to close it).

Comment: thenk you very muth guys. you very halp me. im sucsess :)..

Comment: @ExpressHaifa I think it is considered good form for you to answer your question with the correction needed at this point.